# XSLT 2.0 key() function not working if passed multiple values to match

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, exslt

I'm currently trying to fetch the element node using key() function in XSLT 2.0 by passing multiple values like below

```
      <xsl:key name="orderMovementByAttr1" match="ns0:OrderMovement" use="ns0:FlexFieldStrings/ns0:Attribute1"/>

 <xsl:function name="func:orderMovementByAttr1-group">
    <?audit suppress oracle.ide.xml.validation-error?>
    <xsl:param name="release"/>
    <xsl:param name="searchList"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$release">
      <xsl:sequence select="key('orderMovementByAttr1', $searchList)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:function>
```

Calling function from main template like below:

```
func:orderMovementByAttr1-group($vMatchingRelease02, ('SL', 'OB', 'IB_OB'))
```

Even though my input contains data with one of the search element 'OB', key is not returning data.

If i call function like below i'm getting response:

```
 func:orderMovementByAttr1-group($vMatchingRelease02, 'OB')
```

Not working if i call like below i.e. by using sequence or list of values:

```
 func:orderMovementByAttr1-group($vMatchingRelease02, ('SL', 'OB', 'IB_OB'))
```

Comment: Which XSLT 2 processor is that? With Saxon 9.8 at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiynef I have no problems using such a call with a sequence of string values.

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using this XSLT 2.0 transformation within Oracle's SOA suite 12.2.1.3 product. I have checked the documentation but did not find the exact Saxon version what Oracle is using in the product.

Comment: Write a stylesheet that outputs`system-property('xsl:product-name')` and `system-property('xsl:product-version')` to see which processor is used. Try your code in a standalone version of the processor and compare it with the result of Saxon, if there is a difference file a bug on the product you use.